# Activation of network connection failed, DHCP timeout

Tags: networking, dhcp

After a few hours of trial and error, i guess i need some help...

Problem is the following: I am trying to connect to a WIFI network, which has worked for me for the last three months and started to make trouble just three days ago. 19 out of 20 times I try to connect, i get "Activation of network connection failed", 1 out of 20 times it works for some reason. This problem only occurs on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, on my phone aswell as other peoples devices it works without problems.

From the output of `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` I assume that the DHCP fails:
Output for 19 in 20 cases where connection fails:

```
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639995755.0003] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e7c1:a84a:b0ce:e25b.
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Registering new address record for fe80::e7c1:a84a:b0ce:e25b on wlp2s0.*.
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl wpa_supplicant[858]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-68 noise=-114 txrate=1000
Dec 20 11:22:35 gubblgubbl systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 20 11:22:37 gubblgubbl dbus-daemon[820]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=822 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 20 11:22:37 gubblgubbl systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 20 11:22:37 gubblgubbl dbus-daemon[820]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 20 11:22:37 gubblgubbl systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 20 11:22:47 gubblgubbl systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 20 11:23:18 gubblgubbl wpa_supplicant[858]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-62 noise=-114 txrate=1000
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <warn>  [1639995800.6093] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): request timed out
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639995800.6094] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639995800.6094] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639995800.6100] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <warn>  [1639995800.6117] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Ulveskogen'
Dec 20 11:23:20 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639995800.6123] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Output for 1 in 20 cases where connection works:

```
Dec 20 11:08:44 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994924.4631] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 20 11:08:44 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e7c1:a84a:b0ce:e25b.
Dec 20 11:08:44 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 20 11:08:44 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Registering new address record for fe80::e7c1:a84a:b0ce:e25b on wlp2s0.*.
Dec 20 11:08:44 gubblgubbl wpa_supplicant[858]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=-115 txrate=1000
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '86400'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option expiry               => '1640081327'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option host_name            => 'gubblgubbl'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.57'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.57.
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3827] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option next_server          => '192.168.1.1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl avahi-daemon[813]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.57 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3828] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl whoopsie[11938]: [11:08:47] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3829] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3830] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3830] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3830] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3830] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option wpad                 => '#012'
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3830] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3848] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3903] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3909] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3918] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3935] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3936] policy: set 'Ulveskogen' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec 20 11:08:47 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994927.3943] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 20 11:08:50 gubblgubbl NetworkManager[822]: <info>  [1639994930.8331] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 20 11:08:50 gubblgubbl whoopsie[11938]: [11:08:50] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/38
Dec 20 11:08:50 gubblgubbl whoopsie[11938]: [11:08:50] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/38
Dec 20 11:08:50 gubblgubbl whoopsie[11938]: [11:08:50] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/38
Dec 20 11:08:51 gubblgubbl whoopsie[11938]: [11:08:51] online
```

These are the parts that i think are relevant, if more info is needed please tell me.

What confuses me the most is, that it actually works every now and then. But unfortunately I could not identify anything specific when it worked. Additionally, I know that my laptop works with other WIFIs perfectly, and once again I can't identify anything that would hint at a solution for my problem. This is the reason why I haven't tried the numerous suggestions from other "Activation of network connection failed"-Questions on SE, since my case therefore seems to differ from these. (And i didn't want to risk completely cutting of my laptp from the internet (I don't have LAN available), which would make asking this question rather difficult)

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: Try resetting your WiFi router / modem.

Comment: Would you add output of  `sudo lshw -c network` and also see if `iw event -t` gives more debugging info. Btw, 2nd DHCP in the network may create same behavior some machines can't connect, See if static IP works?